# Add Delivery Date from the Product Custom Option to Sales Order Grid in magento

Tags: grid, magento-1.7, ecommerce-sales

I have added Delivery Date as a Custom Option on the Product. I want the Delivery Date to be displayed in the Sales Order Grid in admin.
I have created my local copy of `Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid`.

Here in the `_prepareCollection()` function I am able to get the Product Options:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
    ->join(
    'sales/order_item',
    '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
    array(
        **'proptions' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.product_options SEPARATOR ",")'),**
    )
);
```

I then add the column as:

```
$this->addColumn('proptions', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Product Options'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'index'     => 'proptions',
        'renderer'  =>  new Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data(),
    ));
```

Now in `Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data()` I have a method:

```
public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());  // row value
    $array = unserialize($val);

    //loop thru the $array and create a format string
    //
    $options = $array['options'];
    $format_val = '';
    foreach ($options as $key=> $value) {
        $format_val = $format_val . $key . "=>" . $value . " , ";
    }

    return $format_val;
}
```

The display is not right. I don't think I'm looping through the array correctly.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hi, THe issue seems to be because of incomplete value returned by query:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in direct sql quesries open this file., ->app->design->adminhtml->default->default->template-> your template ->info.phtml and add this code

```
<div class="entry-edit">
            <div class="entry-edit-head">
                <h4 class="icon-head head-products"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery Time Information') ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid np">

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
//$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');//for writing to database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

$results = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
foreach($results as $result) {
  echo $result['column_name']."<br/>";
} 
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by updating MySQL:
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

This can be set on the Global level as well. 
Thanks,
Neet